# Getting the XML request from ClientBase<T>

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I am currently using [ClientBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access a web service. This works correctly but I need to log the XML request that is being sent off to the service.

I can see that there are ways of doing this using listeners and other similar methods, but I need to access this XML request in the method from which it is being submitted in my codebase.

Is there any way in which this is supported?

Answer (score 1):

The "XML" is only ever created (serialized) after the control flow leaves your method and enters the WCF code that actually does the call. So if you were theoretically able to get it from within your code, you'd have to get it "after" the actual call. This is also the reason why the intended way to do this, is [implement/register a IClientMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786.aspx).

The only other thing, which includes some unnecessary manual labor, would be to manually serialize the arguments you pass to the WCF call using the NetDataContractSerializer or DataContractSerializer. Mind you, though that this will only give you the payload, not the complete message (including headers, etc.).

I'd really go for the way that is suggested for this (see link above).

Answer (score 0):

You can try some AOP programming. If you are using Unity for DI, you can try Unity with Interception or Interception alone using Intercept class.